# Where am I doing wrong in my theme menu?

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes

Every thing works fine out of WordPress but the theme's dropdown menu doesn't work.

Here is my `functions.php` code :

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => esc_html__('Primary', 'codeha'),
));
```

My `header.php` file :

```
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'menu_id' => 'primary-menu',
        'container' => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'primary_nav_div',
        'container_id' => 'primary_menu',
        'menu_class' => 'menu',
        'menu_id' => 'primary_menu_ul'));
    ?>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#primary_menu ul li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(400);
    });
});
```

And my stylesheet:

```
#primary_menu ul{
    margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;background:#252525;text-align:center;position:relative;
}

#primary_menu ul li{display:inline-block;}

#primary_menu ul li a{display:block;height:45px;width:150px;color:#fff;font-family:helvetica;line-height:43px;text-decoration:none;transition: background 0.5s linear 0s, color 0.5s linear 0s}

#primary_menu ul li a:hover{background:#f0300b;color:#781705;}

#primary_menu ul ul{position:absolute;width:150px;display:none;}
#primary_menu ul ul li{display:block;background:#252525;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the java script code in footer.php after wp_footer(); code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("#primary_menu ul li").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(400);
});
```

});

Remove the dolar sign is not compatible in Wordpress in this case.